# How to create an android internet-app, users interact directly with each other

Tags: android, server, p2p

I want to create an app in which the users send any type of data directly to each other through internet.

By directly I mean I don't want to save data on server and then forward to another user. (of course no problem with using a server but I want the server task to be just about introducing clients to each other)

Does android volley networking library do this for me?

If not I'll be glad if anybody can give me advice on how to start or which library to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using GCM.

Here is the detailed tutorial:

http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/

Comment: tnx but does GCM support a scenario in which users interact together directly? for example for chatting. I want client to chat and send files directly. because my server is not very fast and strong that could support thousands of tasks. I think I have to use server just for introducing client to each other

Comment: Yes exactly just introduce them to each other by sharing their devicetokens(you get when registered to GCM) to each other. And for sending files, GCM currently accepts only 4k data per message. So you could upload files to somewhere and send link through GCm. Alternatively you could use UrbanAirship's Rich Push through which you can send files.

Comment: but I think users have a set up a google account on their devices. I want my app to be independent. what's your suggestion? show me the way please :-(

Comment: Yea they must have Google Account. Otherwise you can't use GCM. By the way are you not planning to release your app on Google Play Store? In that case, only users with Google Account can download your app.

Comment: Otherwise you can think of creating your own XMPP client.

Comment: thanks for answering, unfortunately no, I'm not going to release it on Google play, I live in Iran and I face many problems, first Google prohibit iraninans to publish their apps on Google play and second I can not sell it on Google play because iranian banks are banned too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use p2p connection if you dont want to use any server. I suggest that you read this [P2P](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) before writing code. There is a example of wifidirect  [P2P Android Example](https://github.com/huangjunkun/WiFiDirectDemo)